# Cleaner workflow with panel data in pandas and statsmodels: panel, dataframe with multiindex, or plain dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

Imagine I have an [unbalanced panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) such as:

```
Firm  Year   y    x
   A  1990   1.1  2.2
   A  1991   2.1  3.2
   B  1990   4.1  9.2
   B  1991   5.2  10.1
   B  1992   5.3  10.1
```

etc...

I'm reasonably new to Pandas and Statsmodels and am curious what structure has a cleaner workflow for typical panel data?

- A dataframe with no special indexing?
- A dataframe with a multiindex over firm and year?

  - eg. `set_index(['year','firm'])`
- A pandas.Panel?

If I were in SQL, (year, firm) would be the primary key. My instinct is that a multiindex best captures the structure of the data and various use cases? Is that a sensible data structure if I want to run a panel regression with firm or year fixed effects in statsmodels? Is using a multiindex so clunky it's not worth the bother if performance isn't an issue?

Comment: personally I like to use a dataframe without multi-indices, unless I have a particular reason not to. All code for filtering/conditioning will look the same if all the columns are "columns" as opposed to indices, kinda like in SQL (at least how I used it) where even primary key columns are still columns. Also, some functions in statsmodels or sklearn don't play great with Pandas, and its nice to get all my data in a numpy 2-D array/table with my_dataframe.values. Not sure how that would work with a panel or multi-indexed dataframe. Interested in other people's answers though...

Comment: If they are regular columns, then it is easy to use formulas in statsmodels with patsy to generate the dummy variables, when year is specified as categorical. Outside of time series analysis and datetime indices, statsmodels doesn't use the information in an index or multiindex, except to hold on to it to return pandas Series for some results.